# How is the signature in an https request encrypted?

Tags: python, http, encryption, https

I captured this https request from my Android phone.

```
GET https://picaapi.picacomic.com/init?platform=android HTTP/1.1
accept: application/vnd.picacomic.com.v1+json
time: 1579258278
nonce: b4cf4158c0da4a70b4b7e58a0b0b5a55
signature: 65448a52a6d19ceecf21d249ae25e564b61425b4d371f6a20fb4fcbbb9131d9d
app-version: 2.2.1.3.3.4
```

After replaying it in Fiddler for several times, it became obvious that the site checks these two values,'nonce' and 'signature', before giving a response, otherwise the response only contains an error code. Since I wanted to use this api to request for contents of the site, I need to know how these two values are encrypted.

Comment: The signature seems to be a 256 bits long cryptographic hash of some data. Most likely the nonce, time and a secret key are involved, making is impossible to replicate the request without further knowledge.

Comment: It's not clear why you think your conclusion is valid, much less obvious. More likely some things are simply generated uniquely for each request or session.

Comment: It seemed I did make a mistake. I am new to programming and thanks a lot for your help.^_^

Comment: Searching for "picacomic api" finds a few API clients in the wild. The signature is indeed an HMAC, so you need a key to compute them. [Here's one implementation in Kotlin](https://github.com/czp3009/picacomic-api/blob/9b5e369bd2c69bf13afe3993a263d9348aa1f3af/src/main/kotlin/com/hiczp/picacomic/api/PicaComicClient.kt#L57-L61).